# How to set the Kerberos default_ccache_name attribute on a client without using KRB5CCNAME?

Tags: linux, unix, kerberos, aix

According to the MIT Kerberos documentation, the default credential cache name is determined as follows:

> **Default ccache name**
>
> The default credential cache name is determined by the following, in
>   descending order of priority:
>
> ```
> 1. The KRB5CCNAME environment variable. For example, KRB5CCNAME=DIR:/mydir/.
> 2. The default_ccache_name profile variable in [libdefaults].
> 3. The hardcoded default, DEFCCNAME.
> ```

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/ccache_def.html

I'm wondering if there's a way to define default_ccache_name profile variable (#2) on the client side?  I've tried defining it as follows in /etc/krb5.conf on one of my client machines:

```
[libdefaults]
        ...
        default_ccache_name = FILE:/var/krb5/security/creds/krb5cc_%{uid}
        ...
```

But the client binaries (klist / kinit / kdestroy etc.) seem to ignore this completely:

```
[~]$ klist
klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_34125)
```

I'm running version 1.9.4:

```
[~]$ klist -V
Kerberos 5 version 1.9.4
```

Comment: Curiously, your example with editing /etc/krb5.conf works on my machine. Are you certain your environment doesn't have a KRB5CCNAME variable, or there's only one default_ccache_name defined in krb5.conf, or /etc/krb5.conf is actually used and not another .conf file in case you've installed the kerberos applications yourself etc.

Comment: It must have to do with the version.  According to the most recent documentation, parameter expansion of things like `%{uid}` wasn't added until 1.11: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#parameter-expansion.  I also can't find any reference to `default_ccache_name` in the 1.9.4 documentation for `krb5.conf`.  My guess is the library just silently ignores any parameter definitions it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drat, I think I found my own answer -- version 1.9.4 doesn't have this parameter:

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-1.9/krb5-1.9.4/doc/krb5-admin.html

It would help to look in the right documentation...